# How do I know which CG/CF objects need to be released when using ARC?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I understand NSObject instances are handled through ARC, and CG references are not (not sure about CF objects).

I have a memory leak which I found using Instruments, a CFString object that keeps growing and growing. I did a search in my app, and there is no use of CFString, so I think it's embedded in some other framework object that I need to release.  However, I don't know which objects need to be released and which don't.  I have analyzed the app and it's clean with respect to memory leaks.

So, is there some definitive doc that says which objects need to be released?

Comment: Hahaha, you think Apple would make it as easy as giving you documentation?

Comment: Hahaha... then how does one know when/if to release an object when using ARC?

Comment: More seriously, in general if it has `Create` in the function name and/or it's actually creating and returning something (as opposed to operating on an existing object) you need to release it. Otherwise, you usually don't.

Comment: How about "CGRectMake" which returns a rectangle?

Comment: `CGRect` is not an object.

Comment: `CGRectMake` returns a struct directly, not a pointer. You don't (and can't) release plain structs.

Comment: I understand... so, does this apply to CG AND CF functions?  any others?

Comment: An object is a chunk of heap-allocated memory, referred to via a pointer, with the first 8 bytes of it being a pointer to a Class. A CGRect returned from a function is a chunk of stack allocated memory, referred to by value, with no class pointer.

Comment: (More concisely, an object type is declared with @interface and a struct type is declared with struct)

Comment: OK... one last Q: so in the case of UIPopovers, there is nothing to release?  The reason I ask is that each and every time I tap an area on a UIView and the UIPopover appears, memory goes up and is not released.  The popover is created and presented in one class, while the logic for the popover is handled in another class (it has several modal views).

Comment: If you are using ARC, you can not call `-release` on any ObjC object. So I'm not certain what you mean by "is nothing to release." There is plenty of releasing going on; it's being inserted by the compiler.

Comment: I need to go through my code and see what's causing the memory not to be released...

Comment: @Kevin If it has `Create` or `Copy` in it's function name…

Comment: The Create rule is fully detailed here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html

Comment: @Abizern Yes, `Copy` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, is it a `CFString` or an `NSCFString`? `NSCFString` is the bridging class, and it can often show up in places that `NSString` is in your code.

To debug your specific problem, start by looking at the stack trace that Instruments provides. It will tell you where the object was created. That will often help you know what object it is that's leaking, which you can then use to hunt down your mistake.

To your general question, almost all objects must be released. The question is whether ARC inserts the releases for you. I know that sounds pedantic, but it's an important distinction. ARC is not garbage collection. It simply inserts memory calls in a very deterministic way at compile time, if enabled, for ObjC object types and a few object types that can behave as ObjC object types (specifically `dispatch_` types). There are several cases where a given object may require manual memory in one place, but receive automatic memory management in another. Remember that `CFStringRef` and `NSString` are toll-free bridged. A given object can be treated as either, and so may be ARC managed in some cases but not others. Also, ARC may not be enabled on all compile units (`.m` files).

As @Catfish_Man explains, you can recognize ObjC objects by their `@interface` declarations.

Comment: Very clear... thank you for the details... I appreciate it... SD

Comment: There is one set of exceptions to the @interface rule, sadly. All dispatch_* and xpc_* types are ObjC, but that isn't immediately obvious from the header.